# Apex admin log in locked

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

Apex administrator login screen is locked. I can login using other schema but admin login shows locked.[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQSEy.jpg)

Comment: I saw these instructions for an earlier version, http://oracle-noob.blogspot.co.uk/2014/05/unlock-apex-admin-user.html?m=1. Not sure it applies for your version.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I changed my password from command line using below commands

    ->sqlplus/nolog
    SQL>conn system/sys as sysdba
    SQL>@C:\apex\apxchpwd.sql
    Enter the administrator's username [ADMIN] admin
    User "admin" exists.
    Enter admin's email [demo@email.net] demo@email.net
    Enter admin's password []
    Changed password of instance administrator ADMIN.

Comment: yes, the `apxchpwd.sql` script is the standard approach (e.g. we see section 5.4.3.2 explicitly state this solution, https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/install.50/e39144/epg.htm#HTMIG29343)